# BackboneJS - Reusing a panel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've written the below bootstrap snippet which can give me a basic accordion panel. I would like to make this a backbone view (or may be a template) so that it can be reusable,

Can some help me out on this please?.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
              <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading panelBg">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1 <div style="float:right;padding-right:13px"><0a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-mini"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></a><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-mini"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></a></div>
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" style="color:white" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">

                  </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                  <div class="accordion-inner">
                    Anim pariatur cliche...
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Pick a templating system (eg. Handlebars)

Step #2: Put that HTML somewhere that your code can access it (either inside a script tag on the page or inside a Javascript string in your code)

Step #3: Make the `render` method of your `Backbone.View` use that template, along with your templating system, to generate the rendered HTML; apply that html to the view's el (`this.$el.html(...`)

Step #4: Profit!